# Generating folders using textboxes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, textbox

Hello experts,                                                                              I have to generate series of folders from a `TextBox` into specified location.I am having two textboxes to specify the limit of folders(say 30 folders).The problem am facing is that the folder names that i will be providing are alpha-numeric(say 121cs3h101) .

How to set limit when i provide an alpha-numeric values?

(For example: i provide `textbox1=12cs3h101` and `textbox2=12cs3h131` , i need the series limit to be generated). I am working with visual studio 2013 in c# windows form application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the pattern you use for naming the folders?

Comment: There are no specified patterns @Milad Qasemi

Comment: do you take only the last number into account? 101, 102, 103, .... 131 ? or do you take all numbers into account?

Comment: we consider only the last three digits to provide limit. @MongZhu

Comment: can you provide the structure of the naming procedure? is it always 12cs3h ? or does it at least have a system?

Comment: yeah that remains the same 12cs3h

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok I will try to give you a lead.

To parse a string or find specific characters one can use [RegEx.Match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0z2heewz(v=vs.110).aspx) or a simler method called [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx). In both cases you have to be aware how your string is structured and how it can vary. The limits of variation are very important.

If as you say the beginning is always`"12cs3h"` you can either split the string at the character 'h'.

```
string[] sa = s.Split('h');
```

Or you can even use the index of 'h' (since the length seems to be fixed) and take the rest of the string to get the numbers.

```
int index = s.IndexOf('h');
```

The rest is up to you, ... convert, enumerate and so on.

EDIT: There is a nice method that does the enumeration job for you: [Enumerable.Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx) Good luck

Comment: OK sir, thank you i will try with this. @Mong Zhu

Comment: @warriors you are welcome. One more tip: if the beginning is always the same you could write it in the code inside a fixed string like: `string begin_file_name = "12cs3h"` and in the textboxes take only the numbers that you use to make the range. This way you only need to concatenate the new numbers to your `begin_file_name` variable to create the names

Comment: Care to comment on the downvote?